# django - dynamic filed - error : Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-forms

I have the following models.

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=75,null=False,blank=False, unique=True)
    parent=TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True)

class ProductGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=False, blank=False)
    category=TreeForeignKey('category.Category', null=False,blank=False)

class Product(models.Model):
    product_group=models.ForeignKey('productgroup.ProductGroup', null=False,blank=False)
    manufacturer=models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, null=False,blank=False)
    product_type=models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=PRODUCT_TYPE,)
    opening_stock=models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

Here's my view and form.

```
class CreateProduct(CreateView):
    model=Product
    form_class=ProductForm

class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            user = kwargs.pop('user','')
            super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['category']=TreeNodeChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all())
            self.fields['category'].required = False
            self.fields['product_group']=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ProductGroup.objects.none())
            original_fields = self.fields

            new_order = OrderedDict()
            for key in ['category','product_group', 'manufacturer', 'product_type', 'wheel_position', 'opening_stock']:
                new_order[key] = original_fields[key]
            self.fields = new_order
        class Meta:
            model = Product     
            fields=['product_group', 'manufacturer', 'product_type', 'wheel_position', 'opening_stock']
```

**GetProductGroups Ajax View**

```
def GetProductGroups(request):
    product_groups=ProductGroup.objects.filter(category__id=request.GET.get('id'))
    to_json = []
    for pg in product_groups:
        # for each object, construct a dictionary containing the data you wish to return
        mydict = {}
        mydict['id'] = pg.id
        mydict['name'] = pg.name
        to_json.append(mydict)

    response_data = json.dumps(to_json)

    return HttpResponse(response_data, content_type="application/json")
```

**jquery ajax query in product_form.html**

```
<script>
$("#id_category").change(function () {
  var category = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    method:'get',
    url: '/ajax/get_product_groups/',
    data: {
      'id': category
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {

        $('#id_product_group').empty()
        $('#id_product_group').append(
                 $('<option></option>').val(0).html('------------')
             );
        $.each(data, function(key, value){
            $('#id_product_group').append(
                 $('<option></option>').val(value.id).html(value.name)
             );
        });
    }
  });

});
</script>
```

**new url-pattern**

```
url(r'ajax/get_product_groups/', GetProductGroups, name='ajax_get_product_groups'),
```

The jquery script perfectly fetches the data on Category selection, **however**  when press the submit button I get the following validation error - across product-group filed.

> Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available
>   choices.

..and the corresponding dropdown gets emptied too.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Thanks.

[screenshot of the form after submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3MtG.png)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know about how to connect the newly created field with the existing one. `filter(category=self.data.get('category')))` did the trick

```
self.fields['product_group']=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ProductGroup.objects.filter(category=self.data.get('category')))
```